# Xcode 9 (beta 3) / iOS: Adding files to a project - how to make it copy the files into the project's directory

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ide

Lately I've been having to update my older 32-bit Enterprise projects to 64-bit. The easiest way for me to do it is to just start over, but copying many of the files (such as images and sound files) from the old project's folder. I'm finding that when I use the "Add files" feature, the files don't exactly copy from the older folder, they just reference from there. Because I am OCD, I'd like to keep the old and new folders separate.

So my question is, is there a way to set Xcode to copy the files to the new project's folder? I know I can just copy the files from one folder to another using Finder, but I would like to have Xcode do it for me on a case-by-case basis.

If I drag and drop from the finder, Xcode will ask if I want to copy the file "if necessary." I always select that option, but I don't know what "if necessary" means, and it never does that. It would be great to have the ability to force copy the file.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue with **Xcode 9 Beta**.

- This is a bug in xcode 9 beta.
- Just now i tried xcode 8.0. Drag and drop worked fine. You can user any other stable version of xcode to copy files.
- **FYI** Stable version of xcode 9 has been launched this may be fixed in that. Just take a look at it [Xcode 9.](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12)